# HBase : when HTableInterface.batch returns, have changes been applied or just queued?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, batch-processing

We're using the 0.94.6-cdh4.5.0 Java client.

The `batch` method returns an `Object[]` indicating success/failure for the individual requests in that batch. Does a "success" there guarantee that the change has been successfully applied to the master datastore, or just that it's been validated and queued on the server side for future commit? To put it another way, is it reliably safe to access data written as part of a batch **immediately** after `batch` returns success?

I have two reasons for asking:

- We had an operational issue recently in which it *looked* as if a bunch of `batch` calls failed to "take" without reporting that fact. I'd like to rule out the possibility that we're using the API wrong.
- We have a forced wait at one point. I think this is just legacy cruft from an older version of the system which used `put` and `flushCommits` rather than `batch`, and I'd like to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe to access data that has just been written, take a look at this: http://hbase.apache.org/acid-semantics.html

**Visibility**

When a client receives a "success" response for any mutation, that mutation is immediately visible to both that client and any client with whom it later communicates through side channels.

Comment: Thanks. To clarify in case anyone else finds this, that page is part of the 2.0 docs, but the 0.94 book [refererences](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book.html#acid) it so I think we're good.